# url is redirecting to index action only in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new in Yii .
I have created a URL http://enqphp.intermesh.net/enquiry/createFolder in my main.php file to redirect to an action ,but its redirecting to index action only by default .while when I am calling the same like http://enqphp.intermesh.net/index.php?r=/enquiry/Enquiryser/createFolder its working fine .
When I print `$_REQUEST` in my action I am getting

```
Array ( [r] => /enquiry/Enquiryser/index )
```

in index action .

Below is the code that I have used for redirection:

```
 //'caseSensitive' => true,
//'urlSuffix' => '/',
//'showScriptName' => false,
'urlFormat' => 'path',
'rules' =>
array(
    '/' => array('site/index'),

    /* my files starting from here */
    //'/enquiry/createFolder/'=>'enquiry/Enquiryser/CreateFolder',
    '/enquiry/createFolder/' => array('enquiry/Enquiryser/CreateFolder'),
    'enquiry'=>array('enquiry/Enquiryser/index'),
    '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<modules>/<controller>/view', '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*' => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',


),
    )
```

can anyone please help me, what is the issue ?

Comment: Can you try uncommenting `showScriptName`? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the `module->controller->action` in your rules as an `Array`; it should be a `String`.

So your rules should look something like this

```
'/enquiry/createFolder/' => 'enquiry/Enquiryser/CreateFolder',
'enquiry'=> 'enquiry/Enquiryser/index',
```

Comment: I tried the same too ,but still index action is getting called